# trouble editting a jquery function that contains onclick and animate

Tags: jquery, css, decimal, jquery-animate

Wanting to remove the decimal places within this current "jquery" function, I read that it is "to.fixed()", i just don't know where to type it in???

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click(function() {
    $("#number").animate({value: '250px'});
  })
});
```

link to example: ["onclick with animate example"](https://codepen.io/dizzyflex/pen/wvxBMOR)